# When to apply data transformations when building ml model

Tags: cross-validation, feature-selection, feature-scaling

I'm experiancing quite severe overfitting when building my model and wanted some clarification.

I am applying feature selection, scaling , over sampling and outlier removal.

1) Should I transform the data PRIOR to cross validation

OR

2) Fit each transformer on the Training data on each fold.

I believe it to be option 2 and was on the understanding that you fit/transform on the training set and only transform the validation set?

But... reading this article it seems he believes scaling should be done prior?

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-short-introduction-to-model-selection-bb1bb9c73376?gi=3b4c661086bd

> What about preprocessing such as feature selection? As a rule of
>   thumb, supervised preprocessing (involving the data labels) should be
>   done inside the (inner) CV loop [2]. In contrast, unsupervised
>   preprocessing such as scaling can be done prior to cross-validation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the default should be to treat preprocessing as part of model training, i.e. do this inside the cross validation loop.

You can save computation in some cases by "pulling" the transformation before the cross validation. This is allowed as long as the transformation does not violate statistical independence. So transformations that involve each case totally separately from all other cases are OK to do outside the cross validation loop.

In your case,

- feature selection: involves multiple cases -> must be inside cross validation
- scaling:

  - scaling variates/features: involves multiple cases -> must be inside cross validation
  - scaling of cases (e.g. intensity normalization of spectra): is applied to each case independent of all other cases -> can be outside
- over sampling: possible to do outside the cross validation loop, iff splitting is done by independent cases (i.e. all copies of a case end up in the same fold).
- outlier removal: again depends on the method.

  - Iff the method determines for each case whether it is an outlier without referring to any other case (e.g. removing cases with detector saturation) -> can be done outside.
  - If the outlier detection refers to the distribution cases -> dependent, must be done inside cross validation.

---

> As a rule of thumb, supervised preprocessing (involving the data labels) should be done inside the (inner) CV loop [2].

Yes.

> In contrast, unsupervised preprocessing such as scaling can be done prior to cross-validation.

No, unsupervised is necessary, but not sufficient here. In particular there are types of scaling that must be done inside (see above). For those, above advise is plain wrong.

---

One rule of thumb that I like is:

Testing/cross validation simulates predicting cases where the label/outcome is not known.

Think of predicting a small data set of 1 case without outcome/label.

- If the transformation cannot be calculated for this case alone, then it is not independent of label and/or other cases and *must* go inside cross validation.
- If the transformation does not need any further data than the input features of this single case (and possibly pre-specified constants, such as 0 and 1), the transformation is independent of both labels and other cases and may be done beforehand.